# Prerequisites for various math courses

Tags: education

Does anybody know of a list/diagram showing how various math subjects lead to other subjects and their interactions? So like Algebra -> Calculus 1 -> Differential Equations, Calculus 2 -> etc.?

I'm trying to build a solid foundation to get to advanced courses/topics like Real Analysis, Wave Propagation, Numerical Methods, etc. and would appreciate figuring out what's important to know for different topics. Thank you!

Comment: Are you an undergraduate?  Checking the prerequisites listed in an undergraduate course catalog (even if you are not enrolled at this time) would give the kind of "roadmap" you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Somebody apparently created this for my university, and you can find it [here](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~norfolk/Courseflowchart.jpg). Obviously many courses that exist are not listed here, but many of our undergraduate "classics" are. Note that they're prerequisites the department requires, not necessarily prerequisites in some ideal mathematical sense.

Comment: Actually a graduate student trying to go from civil engineering to more math-based computational/engineering mechanics. I didn't work as hard as I should have in some of my undergrad courses but I'm excited to work hard now and trying to figure out how to do it most efficiently. And I'm going to be taking classes that involve functional analysis and similar tough material so I'm trying to start going through the prereqs. The course catalog isn't quite as clear, but it's a good start. Pjs36, thank you! That's really helpfull too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try asking https://academia.stackexchange.com/.

But usually, it's

Basic Math -> Pre-Algebra -> Algebra -> Geometry -> Trigonometry (grade 9 ish) -> precalculus (grade 11) -> calculus (grade 12) -> differential calculus (derivatives and such) (post secondary) -> integral calculus (integrations and such) -> multivariable calculus (with many variables) -> differential equations (this comes far, its not easy) -> linear algebra (not really last but its best learned later on since you won't see the use of it before)

After this, you are open to basically anything.

Comment: Thank you! I'll make sure to go over the calculus courses first, then diffeq and linear algebra and hopefully should be ready for courses like Real Analysis and the like after. I'll also double check with academia, thank you!